# How to cover 'addError' in a test class?

Tags: apex, unit-test, code-coverage, code

I need to cover `AddError()` in my test class.

Apex Class:

```
 public void beforeDelete(SObject so) { 
    Task task = (Task) so; 
    Id sysAdminProfileId = [Select Id From Profile WHERE Name = 'System Administrator'].Id;         
    if(UserInfo.getProfileId() != sysAdminProfileId){             
        Task.addError('You have no permissions to delete tasks.'); 
        return; 
    }       
}
```

Test class:

```
static testMethod void testProfile() {

    Test.startTest();

    Profile p = [select id from profile where name='Management'];
    User u = new User(
        alias = 'ddim', 
        email='noemail@noemail.com', 
        timezonesidkey='America/Los_Angeles', 
        localesidkey='en_US', 
        emailencodingkey='UTF-8', 
        ProfileId = p.Id,
        languagelocalekey='en_US', 
        lastname='Testing', 
        Firstname='Testing', 
        CompanyName= 'xyz', 
        username='dim71@noemail.com');
    insert u;

    Task testTask = new Task(
        subject = 'Test Task',
        priority = 'In Progress',
        OwnerId = u.id
    );

    insert testTask;

    Test.stopTest();

    // Verify that error is thrown when the attachment is deleted
    Boolean errorThrown = false;
    try {
        delete testTask;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.debug(e);
        errorThrown = true;
    }
    System.assert(errorThrown);
}
```

Can someone tell me what I'm missing in my test class in order to get the following covered by my test?

```
Task.addError('You have no permissions to delete tasks.');
```

Thanks for your suggestion but I get the following error message:

> System.DmlException: Delete failed. First exception on row 0 with id 00T9E000004uzukUAA; first error: FIELD_CUSTOM_VALIDATION_EXCEPTION, You have no permissions to delete tasks.: []

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to run as a user who is not a `System Administrator`. You already set one up, now you just need to call `system.runAs`.

```
system.runAs(u)
{
    // delete here and it should fail
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion but I get the following error message:
System.DmlException: Delete failed. First exception on row 0 with id 00T9E000004uzukUAA; first error: FIELD_CUSTOM_VALIDATION_EXCEPTION, You have no permissions to delete tasks.: []

Comment: That is the expected behavior...it should be caught. What line is throwing that error?

Comment: The line in the code is 34